# How can I obtain the access key and secret key in cloud formation in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to get the access key and secret key for a user, while creating the user in CloudFormation.

I followed the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenario-iam-accesskey), and I can get the key in Output TAB. My CloudFormation code look like the following:

```js
"Outputs" : {
  "MyAccessKeyId": {
    "Ref" : "MyAccessKey"
  },
  "MySecretKey": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": [ "MyAccessKey", "SecretAccessKey" ]
  }
}
```

Only issue is that the output contains both access key, and secret key.
So anyone who has access for cloud formation, can get the key.

Is there any way, the secret key would be displayed to me only once, or can be sent to me via mail, when I execute my cloud formation template.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Lambda backed custom resources with cloud formation. Create the user, then have Lambda request secret key/access key, and use SES to email it.

Comment: I too thought so and am already in progress with it. I did not wanted to use lambda initially, as I am not so good with lambda. I was thinking if I can send a sns alert  directly with the required values, without using lambda.

Thanks for the reply. Hope lambda works for me.

Comment: @SureshKumar How did you get on? Would be handy to see what you came up with as I'm trying to do the same thing.